# AllowAnonymous only works intermittently in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

One of my controller actions refuses to authenticate, and I cannot understand why. It's just the standard VerifyCode action from the standard MVC 5 project template in visual studio, and it looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
{
    if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
}
```

Whenever my application hits this controller without a user logged in, it sends the user back to the login screen, even though it's decorated with AllowAnonymous. By contrast, this standard controller action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    return View();
}
```

Works fine if hit directly without a logged in user.

So to try and figure out what's going on, I added the following test actions to my controller:

```
// to see if it's down to the parameters
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult VerifyCode()
{
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = "", ReturnUrl = "", RememberMe = false });
}

// to see if it's down to the action name
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult VerifyCod()
{
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = "", ReturnUrl = "", RememberMe = false });
}

// to see if it's down to the viewmodel
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = "", ReturnUrl = "", RememberMe = false });
}
```

Hitting the first two of these causes my application to send me back to the login page. Hitting the third renders the ForgotPassword view without issues.

I don't have any custom authorization filters. What on earth could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .vs/config/applicationhost.config file and validate the following sections are set to Deny and true.

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
```

Comment: Found them. They're set as described.

Comment: What flags do you have set on the controller itself?